# What exactly is data coupling? What are its downsides?

Tags: design, coupling

I came across it in [this article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/types-of-coupling):

> *You call a method and pass it a parameter that doesn’t affect its control flow.*
>
> This is still coupling, but we’re starting to reach the kind that
>   isn’t so bad. Sometimes you need parameters! If you wanted to remove
>   all coupling you wouldn’t be able to pass data between objects at all.
>
> ```
> class ScreenPrinter
>   # This method is coupled to its parameter, because a change to that argument
>   # can cause breakage (if we undefined to_s, for example).
>   def print(text)
>     output_to_screen(text.to_s)
>   end
> end
> ```

What if the `text` was just a string and `print` passed `text` into `output_to_screen` *without* accessing any of its properties or calling any of its methods, like so:

```
class ScreenPrinter
  def print(text)
    output_to_screen(text)
  end
end
```

Would it still be data coupling? It seems to me like the answer is yes - you can't predict what `print` will do without knowing what data is passed to it.

Is data coupling in such a case a bad thing?

Comment: "What if the test didn't have a to_s method" do you mean what if `print` doesn't invoke `to_s` on `text` but simply passes it into `output_to_screen` without accessing any members of `text`?

Comment: @Samuel yes, that is what I meant, thanks for making that note. I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: It would still be data coupling, as print would effectively be coupled to whatever types output_to_screen is coupled to.

Answer (score 1):

The [only substantial reference](http://www.ldra.com/attachments/category/24/TN%20Data_and_Control_Coupling_v1.0.pdf) I could find to "data coupling" is quite a bit different from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) and article definitions.

In the [LDRA paper](http://www.ldra.com/attachments/category/24/TN%20Data_and_Control_Coupling_v1.0.pdf), data coupling is

> The dependence of a software component on data not exclusively under the control of that software component.

Their example is:

> For this demonstration of a Data Coupling defect consider two functions, CalculateAirspeed
>   and Display-Airspeed both of which are called from the same Main Program
>   (diagram above) and which share a global variable ‘speed’. Calculate-Airspeed
>   computes a value for the variable ‘speed’, i.e. a set operation, whilst the function
>   Display-Airspeed outputs the value of ‘speed’ to a display device, i.e. a use operation.
>   The Main Program may be of the form illustrated below.

```
int main(){
 int speed, order;
loop:
 get(order);
 switch( order ){
 case 1: calculate_airspeed(speed);
 case 2: display_airspeed(speed);
 }
 goto loop;
}
```

The paper says `display_airspeed` is coupled to `speed` because it's declared and set independently of `display_airspeed`. `display_airspeed` will break if the order of operations is switched above.

I don't like this definition because I think spirit of the term data coupling is broader. Yes, `display_airspeed` is data coupled to `speed`, but that's irrelevant to the execution and flow of the program. Their example is more indicative of "Common coupling" according to the Wikipedia entry.

The Wikipedia entry and the article you've read take a broader definition of data coupling. Wikipedia uses:

> Data coupling occurs when modules share data through, for example, parameters. Each datum is an elementary piece, and these are the only data shared (e.g., passing an integer to a function that computes a square root).
>
> What if the text was just a string and print passed text into output_to_screen without accessing any of its properties or calling any of its methods, like so: ... Would it still be data coupling?

Yes. `print` is still data-coupled in two ways.

1. The existence of the parameter `text` is in itself data coupling according to the definition, because removing the parameter and making `print` parameter-less or adding a parameter would be a breaking change. Therefore `print` is data coupled to being passed a single parameter.
2. As @Aelexe says, `print` is coupled to the type of `text`. Even in a dynamically-typed language like your example, if `output_to_screen` expects a `Foo` to be passed in, and I call `print` and pass it a `Bar`, it will break `print` (because print is incorrectly calling `output_to_screen`). Therefore `print` is data-coupled to the `Foo` type transitively because of `output_to_screen`. I'm not actually sure this is data coupling. It may actually be "external coupling" to the type of `text`.

By removing the call to `to_s`, you've removed what I believe is "Stamp coupling (Data-structured coupling)" (from Wikipedia's definition)

> Stamp coupling occurs when modules share a composite data structure and use only parts of it, possibly different parts

In this case `print` only really needs a string, but the parameter is a different type, and `print` accesses the `to_s` member of `text` to retrieve a string value. Therefore `print` is couple to the *structure* of `text` and changing or undefining `to_s` is a breaking change.

Comment: Is data coupling a bad thing?

Comment: All coupling is less desirable than no coupling, but on the scale of coupling data coupling is more loose. I don't think it should be actively avoided like some other kinds of coupling. See this diagram https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)#/media/File:Coupling_sketches_cropped_1.svg

Comment: "All coupling is less desirable than no coupling" -- in fact, coupling is desirable, unless it is not needed. It is unnecessary coupling that is not desirable. Coupling has to do both with data types and a dependency on their structure, but the same word is used for invoking procedures/methods, whereby it is the signature that is treated as a data type. Strong typing is a desirable form of coupling.

Comment: @AdamZerner "coupling" and "decoupled" have been misused recently. "Coupling" refers to call chains and dependencies on data types. This can be signatures or parameters. Adding superfluous interfaces, or switching to a weakly typed language, does not remove coupling, it only obfuscates it. The goal is not to eliminate coupling, but to eliminate unnecessary knowledge about data types: use the most general types, code, and signatures. A second goal is to avoid layer violations: when lower layer data types depend on higher layer data types.